# How to Write text box text into text file in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, file

How can I Write Text Box into text file and save it in c# (Win form)?
I tried this but it does not work:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter sw1 = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\a.txt");
sw1.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
sw1.Close();
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: no error.but don't create anything.

Comment: My answer below works and is only one line of code ^_^

Comment: This code either creates a file or throws an exception. Read [ask] and create a [mcve]. You probably call this code from a `try-catch` with an empty catch, ignoring the exception.

Comment: are you trying to write to C:\Users\.... You might be getting access denied exception, unless you are eating it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literally just use this.

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filepath, text);
```

(I'm not sure, but you may have to change "C:\Users..." to "C:/Users..." and change every pair backwards slashes to a forwards slash.)

P.S: I don't think you have the permissions to write to "C:/Users", use a different directory such as your documents or something.

Comment: NOTE: In this instance, `text` would be `textBox1.Text`.

Comment: Also, there are two options: `"C:\\Users\\..."` or `@"C:\Users\..."`, unless the OP is running a Unix-based system, in which case they would use `"/home/..."`.

Comment: _"Use this other code"_ generally is not the answer to _"Why doesn't this code work"_.

Comment: It's an alternative solution and makes a lot more sense

Comment: It does not make "a lot more sense". In essence it does exactly the same (apart from OP's code adding another newline at the end), `File.WriteAllText()` is just a convenient wrapper method. If OP's code does not work, the problem is either that `textBox1.Text` does not contain the text they expect, or that the code throws because the given path is not writable. In that case, replacing their code with yours (and still using their parameters) does not change anything.

Comment: Can you press the tick please?